# Is there a good bound for $|Y^{T}W^{T}WY-Y'^{T}W^{T}WY'|$?

Tags: matrices

Assuming  $Y,Y'\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $y_{i},y'_{i}\in[-1,1]$ and $Y$ and $Y'$ only differ in $t$-th element.

The upper bound I come out is that
$$|Y^{T}W^{T}WY-Y'^{T}W^{T}WY'|=|(Y+Y')^{T}W^{T}W(Y-Y')|\leq\lambda_{\max}(W^{T}W)\|Y-Y'\|_{2}\|(Y+Y')\|_{2}\leq\lambda_{\max}(W^{T}W)O(\sqrt{n})$$

Is this a tight upper bound? If so, is there any extra condition that can come out a upper bound without $n$?

Comment: I think you need to look at your notation, as it is the term you are trying to bound is just $0$. Some apostrophes seem to be missing.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I've corrected it.

Comment: I think you can get rid of $n$ directly. Because $|(y+y')^T W^T W (y-y')|=|(y+y')^T W^T W \alpha e_t |= \alpha |(y+y')^T W^T W_t | \leq   \alpha \sigma_{\max}(W).$ Where $\alpha = | y_t -y_t'|$

Comment: I don't understand the last inequality. In my opinion, $\|y+y'\|_{2}\leq2\sqrt{n}$